# Javascript optional if else inside constructor

Tags: javascript

Here's the code to start with.

```
function person(name, age, child){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    if(this.child == undefined){
        this.child = 'default';
    }else{
        this.child = child;
    }
}
var sarah = new person('sarah',34,true);

document.write(sarah.child+' ');
```

So I'm trying to make an optional property inside a constructor function. But whatever I put inside the child parameter it always says 'default' when printed out. I am exceedingly new to JS, just came off php. No idea why this isn't working. I've looked at other questions, tried to follow, but what I try from them doesn't seem to help.

Comment: `this.child` is always undefined, since you did not define it (you only defined `this.name` and `this.age`). Btw, you should use `===` to compare with `undefined`.

Comment: you just need to check `child`: `if (child == undefined) {`.

Comment: Oh damn. I took that initial definition out thinking the problem I had before was me defining it twice. Thank-you! And thankyou for the === tip.

Comment: Is 'this' not necessary then? @dfsq

Comment: @RussellKitchen: `child` is the parameter (variable). `this.child` is a property.

Comment: No, `this.child` is a property of the instance, which is always `undefined` before you define it. And you are only defining it later inside if check.

Comment: Aaahhhh. Still getting a handle on everything and the vocab,  but that makes perfect sense. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use `child = child || 'default'` instead of an if else statement?

This achieves the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is below:

```
function person(name, age, child){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    if(child == undefined){
        this.child = 'default';
    }else{
        this.child = child;
    }
}
var sarah = new person('sarah',34,true);

document.write(sarah.child+' '); // true
```

The explanation is that you are always comparing `this.child` with `undefined` but what you want is test the argument `child` instead of `this.child`.

A shortcut can be provided, instead of use `if/else`:

```
this.child = child || 'default';
```